# IEventBroker doesn't sent event in java

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

I want to send success message by `IEventBroker` and listen it from another class. I could not handle the message from listener function. What can be its cause?

I sent the message by this line :

```
eventBroker.post(IBackupRestoreEventConstants.TOPIC_BACKUP_SUCCESS, new Date());
```

I want to handle in this function:

```
@Inject
@Optional
public void whenBackupSuccess(@UIEventTopic(IBackupRestoreEventConstants.TOPIC_BACKUP_SUCCESS) long timeStamp) {
    MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "Information", "Backup operation completed successfully");
}
```

Comment: Is the `whenBackupSuccess` method in a class which is actually injected? Only classes created from the Application.e4xmi are injected automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are posting an event with a `Date` value but you are using `long` as  the argument in `whenBackupSuccess`, the event broker will not do this conversion for you. Since the method is `@Optional` it will just be ignored.

Use `Date` in `whenBackupSuccess`:

```
@Inject
@Optional
public void whenBackupSuccess(@UIEventTopic(IBackupRestoreEventConstants.TOPIC_BACKUP_SUCCESS) Date timeStamp)
```